# ahoy_meta gem don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ahoy

Can anybody please help me how to create a event into ahoy_gem and how the visits will be tracked.
I already follow the documentation provided by the gem developer, but it can't help me how to properly use it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if it track visits,
head to `rails console` and run `Visit.any?` if it returns `true` then it is tracking the visits!

If it doesn't track visits, you can add the code below to `application_controller.rb`:

```
after_action :ahoy_track

protected

def ahoy_track
  ahoy.track_visit
end
```

now it will track the visits.

In order to track events you have 2 options:

1. track events in the server side.
2. track events in the client side using js.

to track in the server side you should use the:

```
ahoy.track "Event name", properties: { one: "val", two: "val" }
```

This will create a record in the db with event named "Event name" with the properties one: "val", two: "val"

to track events in the client side using js:

```
ahoy.track("Event name", {one: "val"});
```

- tracking in js won't create records in the db, but `A POST request is sent to /ahoy/events with` (from the documentation) and you will need to handle it there.

another thing: if you want to check events you can access them as `Ahoy::Event` or from a visit: `visit.ahoy_events`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation? I cannot seem to find anything except the github page which makes no mention of a post request...nor do I see one outgoing in the network pane of dev tools

Comment: Hi, i actually don't remember where i found this in the docs ( its 4 years old :D ), but maybe you can try it yourself, just add the `ahoy.track` function to your js file, and then see what happens...